# Is this 'fun' an adjective or noun?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, parts-of-speech

> Playing tennis is a lot of **fun**.

Is this a structure of 
[adjective: a lot of][**noun**: fun] or [adverb: a lot of][**adjective**: fun]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ describes *a lot of* as a quantifying determiner. That makes the structure of your example [**determiner**: a lot of] [**noun**: fun].

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, *fun* is a noun.

Informally, *fun* can also be a verb ("They are just funning you.") or an adjective ("It was a fun evening."), but this is not the case there.

Answer (score -2):

Fun is a noun. There are many derivatives of the word. Funny is a proper adjective. Funster is someone who likes to have a good time. Fun as a verb goes into the same basket with office and movie both of which are convenient shorthand for people too lazy to put together a proper sentence.
Fun as an adjective, along with "funner" and "funnest" create for me, as well as other educated people I know, an effect similar to fingernails on a blackboard. But for most people, they could (sic) care less.

Comment: So "Bridge is a fun game." would be expressed how by so-called educated people?

Comment: I'm morbidly curious where you could ever have seen someone talking about "officing" or "movieing".

Comment: Go into Office Max on a Saturday morning and hang out at the stationery department.